# How to compute the intersection of two vectors in dolphindb?

Tags: dolphindb

For example, I have two vectors in dolphindb, va = [1,2,3]; vb = [2,3,5]; How can I find the intersection  of va and vb?

[2,3]

Answer (score 0):

va = [1,2,3]
 vb = [2,3,5]

(set(va) & set(vb)).keys()